# React router remounts children while changing routes (without reconciliation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a situation where few routes consists of the same component and I want to preserve its state, but with this behavior it's fairly impossible.

Live example (look at seconds elapsed):
https://csb-43lp1km647-nkiinaibit.now.sh

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/43lp1km647

Of course I could save and restore state of timer while changing routes, but my app has an infinite CSS transition as a background (not on every route).

I was trying adding keys, even portal, but it still remounts everything.

Is there any way to enforce typical React's [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) (remount only elements that have to be remounted)?

**Update**:
Just found out that `<Switch />` will render everything until it finds element that matches, and that could be either a certain `<Route />` or any element except it's inside `<Fragment />`.

Code:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/third" component={RouteWithoutTimer} />
    <React.Fragment>
      <Timer />
      <Route exact path="/" component={FirstRoute} />
      <Route path="/second" component={SecondRoute} />
    </React.Fragment>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit React router remounts children while changing routes]

Or with wildcard route:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/third" component={RouteWithoutTimer} />
    <React.Fragment>
      <Timer />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={FirstRoute} />
        <Route component={NotFoundRoute} />
      </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

It's not a solution I was looking for, but it works fine.

Comment: When i last come across this issue, I just restructured the component tree so that there is only one of the component that gets unmounted (in your case, Timer). Is it possible that you do this? Another thing you can do is lift the timer's state to the app and then pass it as a prop.

Comment: @gorhawk Thanks for response. It's element with CSS transition (background), so state lifting is not possible. Now I have a variable inside app's state which indicates if this element should be rendered and two functions inside app's context, that changes this variable's value. Every route calls adequate function to render/not render background. Wonder if there is a simpler and more elegant solution.

Comment: I wanted to suggest using `react-redux` but it seems to be overkill

Comment: @gorhawk Look at update.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you were familiar with `Switch`, I was referring to something like this. If you call this more elegant, then go with it :D

Answer (score 2):

You are mounting a new instance of `Timer` in each route.
If you want to share a component across routes, you should lift it to the parent component of the routes:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Timer />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={FirstRoute} />
    <Route path="/second" component={SecondRoute} />
  </Switch>
</React.Fragment>
```

[image: Edit React router remounts children while changing routes]

Comment: In this case it works, but if I want to leave one route without ```Timer``` then I would have to implement additional logic in every route.

Comment: What additional logic? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for response. Moving ```<Fragment />``` into ```<Switch />``` solved my problem. Look at update.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the state management libraries come to scene.

In React, states are per component and has lifecycle of it's owned component, so when router destructs/remounts the component, you lose all the data. I advice you to migrate your state to a state management library like `redux` as soon as possible. Otherwise your code can be mess if this is a medium-sized application.